# Javascript page transition undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add page transition to my website. But for some reason when I click on a link it redirects to mywebsite.com/undefined

This is the code I'm using

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.menu-item').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    newLocation = this.href;
    $('.preloader').fadeIn(1000, newpage);
  });

  function newpage() {
    window.location = newLocation;
  }
});
```

I can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're not passing the new location to your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>That's because `newLocation` is out of scope (it is only available in the `click` function's scope).</del> (See Update 1.)

Instead, pass it into the `newPage` function like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.menu-item').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $('.preloader').fadeIn(1000, function() {
        // Pass this.href into the newPage function
        newPage(this.href);
    });
  });

  function newPage(newLocation) {
    window.location = newLocation;
  }
});
```

---

**Notes:**

- Notice that I am passing a function as the second argument to the `.fadeIn` function. (See the [API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/).) You *cannot* just pass `newPage(this.href)` into the second argument because that will pass the *return value* of the `newPage` function (which is null) into the `.fadeIn` function.
- This pattern applies to other jQuery functions such as `.slideUp`. Here's an example of an implementation of `.slideUp`:

  ```
  $('.preloader').slideUp({
      duration: 1000,
      easing: "easeInOutQuint"
  }, function() {
      newpage(this.href)
  });
  ```

---

**Update 1:**

As noted by [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) in the comments, since `newLocation` is not declared with `var` in your code snippet, it should automatically be a global variable. As such, it should actually be in scope in the `newpage` function and the original snippet should actually work.

Comment: Probably better to actually pass `newLocation` in to the function though to save pollution

Comment: @DarrenSweeney, fixed. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Wow. Thank you a ton! Can't mark it the right answer yet but will do asap. And just a quick question, if i'd like it to do a animation. Then it should be something like this right?

$('.preloader').slideUp({duration:1000, easing:"easeInOutQuint"}, newpage);

Comment: @I_ve I just added an example of how you would use the `.slideUp` function.

Comment: Thank you a ton for your help! Really appreciate it.

Comment: Why is `newLocation` out of scope? It's not declared with `var`, so it's a global variable, not a local variable.

Comment: @Barmar, good point. I'm not sure why the OP's code was failing then. My answer seemed to have fixed the OP's problem but I've added an update reflecting your catch.